# get .osm file from .mbtiles file

Tags: openstreetmap, convert, mbtiles

I need to merge data from an OSM map with some other data (tiles) I get from a tileserver. I can import and display both layers well in QGIS and all zoom levels work fine. Now, I would like to export a region of this map as an .osm file so I can use it offline on my mobile phone (the app I am using on the phone can only load .osm files).

What I managed so far: I can export the merged maps from QGIS to an .mbtiles file. I can also extract that file to a folder structure or load the .mbtiles file as a single layer into QGIS again if that helps.

How can I get from the .mbtiles file to the .osm file, or more generally, how do I export the result of a merged OSM map with an tile-server map to single .osm file?

(additional info: I work with Ubuntu 14.04 and QGIS 2.18)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tippecanoe by mapbox to convert MBTILES to GEOJSON layers. Then use ogr2ogr to convert GEOJSON to OSM XML Based file.
A better approach is to use  a mobile app that supports vector tiles MBTILES.

Ok created with QTILES means raster in blob
You can't not make OSM from raster. I thought you had vector tiles with PBF in blob of tile_data in tiles table

Comment: tippecanoe-decode yields the following error: 
$: tippecanoe-decode testfile.mbtiles
{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "properties": {
"bounds": "8.75451840334,45.7940852367,8.84680355959,45.8634521078",
"description": "Created with QTiles",
"format": "png",
"maxZoom": "13",
"minZoom": "0",
"name": "Mapnik",
"type": "baselayer",
"version": "1.1"
}, "features": [
PBF decoding error in tile 0/0/0.  
Looks like the mbtiles file is corrupt?! It is created with the QTiles plugin in QGIS. Any suggestions?

Comment: I saw the app also supports reading from a tile directory structure. QTiles can also export to a directory. The app (G-Vario) can read the data if it is in a folder under sdcard/osmdroid/tiles.  
As a note for others (maybe specific to GVario): the generated tiles are very large in png format and much smaller in jpg format. Only after _renaming_ the "*.jpg" tiles to "*.png.tile" GVario can read them. Note: this is just changing the file name ending, I did _no_ conversion; so the size of the map is still small.
Strange that OSM from raster does not work, seems to me a useful conversion....